# How to check if pointers overlap?

Tags: c, pointers

I've read a a tip here:
http://www.cprogramming.com/tips/showTip.php?tip=183

saying:

> Also monitor that the pointers are not overlapping if not pointing to same memory location range.

How can one monitor such thing? Comparing every pointer to each other is obviously silly.

Comment: Those tips are totally useless. Part of which is because e.g. the one you mention makes no sense at all without context.

Comment: Those 3 "tips" are mostly nonsense.

Comment: You don't *monitor* such a thing, you just make sure it never happens. E.g. do not use the same memory area for src and dst in strcpy(), etc.

Comment: For an example, see this bug report for Adobe Flash, caused by overlapping src and dest when calling `memcpy`: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=638477

Answer (score 2):

You can't, and you shouldn't constantly. This is probably just a debugging hint for some problem the author once encountered, and maybe useful in embedded systems.

In general, `valgrind` helps you more when you have pointer issues than any manual comparison.

Comment: Actually I program embedded systems (no OS), can I use valgrind there (as far as I know that's some unix thing)?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to check overlapping:

```
T *a, *b;
// ...
if (abs((int)((void*)a - (void*)b)) < sizeof(T))
    // overlap
```

But I cannot see any reason to check it.

Comment: According to the standard, you cannot subtract `void` pointers.  Casting to `int` is also incorrect, and will result in truncation on 64-bit systems.  Use `ptrdiff_t` instead.

Comment: *"...I cannot see any reason to check it"* - `memcpy` uses `restrict` pointers. In debug builds it is nice to have the additional diagnostics so the problem of overlappng buffers can be fixed during a debugging cycle, before they make it into production.